# Get JQUERY Dialog working when loading content with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following jquery code:

```
$(".editDialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1000
    },
    hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
    }
});
```

I have several `<div>` elements with class="editDialog".
Everything works very well, but when i load these div's with ajax. The dialogs doesn't work anymore.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/9Wvte/

Here it is working. But when the code in the HTML Section is loaded by ajax, it stops working.

I think i have to change the code above, so that it is called even after document.ready was called.

Comment: What are oyu loading with the AJAX call?

Comment: i load the div boxes and the < a > link. ALL the Code in the HTML section on jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your function in the

```
complete : function(){
/*your function here*/
}
```

in your ajax `POST` function. According to me the even is bound before the elements are created in the DOM. Running the function here will trigger it after the ajax has loaded the DOM hence it will be bound to all the elements.

Comment: but when having also div boxes loaded by reloading the page without ajax, i need the function twice right?

Comment: No my friend. You just need to trigger it in 
$(document).ready(function(){}); when using without ajax. Just keep this in mind the function binding the events to the div should be triggered after all the divs are created on the page.

Comment: But how to call the function. I mean. At the moment i have my code like in my question above in the document.ready function and the same code when ajax is complete. How can i make just one function and call it when ajax is delete and when document is ready? Thank you so much.!!