# Same script for mutiple div classes

Tags: javascript, css

I'd like a way to use the same script for multiple object because I have to replicate this for 50 times.

What the script does is that when you click on a button it should open a popup style image with a frame in it for every product with its gallery.

I'm currently using this :

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#popup").click(function(){
                $("#overlay").fadeIn(500);
                $("#overlay_div").fadeIn(500);
            });
            $("#close_botton").click(function(){
                $("#overlay_div").fadeOut(500);
                $("#overlay").fadeOut(500);
            });
        });  
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#popup1").click(function(){
                $("#overlay1" ).fadeIn(500);
                $("#overlay_div1").fadeIn(500);
            });
            $("#close_botton1").click(function(){
                $("#overlay_div1").fadeOut(500);
                $("#overlay1").fadeOut(500);
            });
        });  
    </script>
            <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#popup2").click(function(){
                $("#overlay2").fadeIn(500);
                $("#overlay_div2").fadeIn(500);
            });
            $("#close_botton2").click(function(){
                $("#overlay_div2").fadeOut(500);
                $("#overlay2").fadeOut(500);
            });
        });  
    </script>
```

---

```
<div id="overlay"></div>
        <div id="overlay_div">
        <div id="close_botton">X</div>
        <iframe src="galleria.html"; scrolling="auto" width="800px" height="700px">b</iframe>
        </div>
```

Comment: Show the html code. It will help a lot.

Comment: Duplication question [jquery-selector-for-id-starts-with-specific-text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23223526/jquery-selector-for-id-starts-with-specific-text)

Comment: @mplungjan - Solution provided by you is also there in duplicate question as an alternate option which is recommended.

Comment: @Gaurav - I see it is. Closed as duplicate. The missing bit is navigating to the things to show and hide

Comment: @Alessandro, we need to see the popup button if you want the complete solution

Answer (score 1):

You need a class and you can access the others relative to the object

```
<div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="overlay_div">
    <div class="close_botton">X</div>
    <iframe src="galleria.html"; scrolling="auto" width="800px" height="700px">b</iframe>
</div>
```

using - for now - I need to see the popup button code too - if the popup is next to, before the div, `$(this).next()` would find the div

```
$(function(){
  $(".popup").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find(".overlay").fadeIn(500);
    $(this).parent().find(".overlay_div").fadeIn(500);
  });
  $(".close").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find(".overlay").fadeOut(500);
    $(this).parent().find(".overlay_div").fadeOut(500);
  });
});
```

change `parent().find` to whatever matches the button's access to the overlays - show HTML to allow us to see what the selectors should be - for example `$(this).closest("div.productContainer")` instead