# Accessing formvalues dynamically with similar name

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have a WebForm with dynamically created fields like:

```
name_1
name_2
name_3
```

Using JQuery it got them in a Object using something like:

```
var inputs = $('#'+formId).serializeArray();
$.each(inputs, function (i, input) {
        formObj[input.name] = input.value;
    });
```

Now I want to dynamically access the values in the formObject in a later step,
but I'm stuck on how to access the variable names in a dynamic manner?

This and others did not work:

```
var name = formObj.name + '_' + index;
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: you want the jquery [starts with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) `$( "[name^='name_']" )`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery selector for id starts with specific text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23223526/jquery-selector-for-id-starts-with-specific-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bracket notation allows you to access properties dynamically

```
var name = formObj['name_' + index];
```

You're actually doing exactly that in your existing code: `formObj[input.name] = input.value`

Comment: [starts with selector or a class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23223564/542251) would be a much better solution

Comment: @Liam That's for DOM nodes, OP is storing the values from form elements in a plain JS object for use at a later time. jQuery selectors don't apply here.

Comment: Dull. Sorry, right. Maybe I should have a break. Thanks.