# Javascript click button starting with word

Tags: javascript, jquery, applescript

I am trying to click a button based on the fact that it is starting with the id "submitButton_" given that what comes afterwards keeps on changing (e.g. "submitButton_10a313c673cee"). This is what the button looks like:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button" id="submitButton_10a313c673cee">Continue</a>
```

using the following code, I can click the button:

```
tell application "Safari" 
    do JavaScript "$(id='submitButton_10a313c673cee').click();" in document 1
end tell
```

Therefore, from other questions (e.g. [jquery selector for id starts with specific text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23223526/jquery-selector-for-id-starts-with-specific-text)) I thought I could click it using:

```
do JavaScript "$(id^='submitButton_').click();" in document 1
```

However, this does not work. I also tried multiple permutations all of which didn't work, e.g.:

```
do JavaScript "$('[id^=submitButton_]').click();" in document 1
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Last one seems to work on Chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/Lhmvh8ms/1/

Comment: Are you typing *exactly* what you say you've tried, literally the whole of `do JavaScript "$('[id^=submitButton_]').click();" in document 1` including the `do JavaScript` and surrounding the jQuery portion with quotes?

Comment: @DavidThomas I typed exactly as posted. I have now added to my question that I am running this in applescript for Safari.

Comment: @user3439894 Unfortunately, I can't. One has to login to this database.

Comment: Have you tried `do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('btw btn-default')[0].click();" in document 1`, assuming this is the only or first `class="btw btn-default"` on the page?

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks! I had tried that. Unfortunately, it's not the first (and I couldn't figure out the how many th it is)

Comment: Is it the only button on the page that says "Continue"?

Comment: @user3439894 Yes, and I have tried to use that. Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out how. Thank you so much for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly, you can do it like below

```
$("[id^=submitButton_]").trigger('click');
```

Comment: It gives me {TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '$('[id^=submitButton_]').click')}

Comment: Also, I am sorry but I am confused about the whole quotes thing. When I run your proposed code it gives me: **Syntax Error Expected end of line, etc. but found “[”.**
So I have to replace the " with ' for it to run...

Comment: Maybe you need to add your question tags "applescript" i didnt get the question totally.  I will still keep the response here though that maybe you would need it later with your scripting language

Comment: Sorry, I added it. I am new to the game and learning. Thanks for the support

Answer (score 0):

Edit -- Based on comments about quotes AND using apple script...

Try this:

```
do JavaScript "$(\"[id^='submitButton_']\").click();" in document 1
```

Comment: You're using single quotes within a single-quoted string, itself inside of a double-quoted string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a JavaScript programmer but do use a bit of JavaScript from time to time, e.g.:

```
do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-default')[n].click();"
```

Where `n` in `[n].click()` is set to the *index number*, to click buttons by their `class name` on various web pages.

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* is what I used to get the *value* of `n` in `[n].click()`:

Set the two *variables* as appropriate and the remaining *code* is tokenized.

In your case, e.g:

```
set theClassName to "btn btn-default"
set theText to "Continue"

tell application "Safari"
    tell document 1 of front window
        set theCount to (do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClassName & "').length;") - 1 as integer
        repeat with i from 0 to theCount
            set innerText to do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClassName & "')[" & i & "].innerText;"
            if innerText is theText then
                do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClassName & "')[" & i & "].click();"
                exit repeat
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

I ran the above in Script Editor on a page that had many *elements* with the `btn btn-default` *class name* and with one having `Continue` as its *inner text*. The last event was:

```
do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-default')[2].click();"
```

So, if you do the same, you should be able to find out the proper *index number* and use it to click the button.

Note that while the *example* **AppleScript** *code* could be used as the normal *code*, it's just meant to get the *index number* and see that it actually clicks the button so you can use the single line of *code* in the actual *script*.