# hide all .closeclass[id] in jquery?

Tags: jquery

Basically I'd like to close all `closeclass[id]`.

```
<div class="closeclass4"></div>
<div class="closeclass15"></div>
<div class="closeclass12"></div>
<div class="closeclass10"></div>
```

```js
$( document ).on( "touchstart", ".comments", function(e) {
  $(".closeclass").hide(); // closeclass always has a number after it
});
```

is it possible?

Comment: Use $("[id^=closeclass]") for all classes beginning with "closeclass". See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376431/wildcards-in-jquery-selectors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery selector for id starts with specific text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23223526/jquery-selector-for-id-starts-with-specific-text)

Comment: it is not starting, it is ending.

Comment: Give them a common class name in addition to the unique ones then the code shown would work

Comment: It's right. You need to select divs has class start with `closeclass`

Comment: Get rid of the numbers after the `closeclass` name as they're redundant. Classes are for grouping elements. Then your problem becomes moot. If you want to identify elements uniquely use `id` or a `data` attribute of some kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael pointed out in the comments, all you need to do is use the `[attribute^=value]` selector. Though since you're using classes, we use `class^=` instead of `id^=`

```js
$("[class^=closeclass]").css('background', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="closeclass4">test</div>
<div class="closeclass15">test</div>
<div class="foo">test</div>
<div class="closeclass10">test</div>
```

Comment: Should stop and figure out why unique classes are used in the first place also

Comment: I do not disagree with that.

Comment: Please note that this will fail if `closeclass` is not listed first, e.g. `<div class="fails closeclass10">test</div>`. I'd go with `$("[class*=closeclass]")` (even if that has fail cases as well, but probably less common).

Comment: it won't fail in jquery.

Comment: @skobaljic It will.

Comment: Yeah but that's a different issue... otherwise, you can use `class~=` - I'm going off the provided code only.

Comment: Yes, just tried, it fails [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7d9qkcbw/), I'd consider it a bug.

Comment: @skobaljic *= is probably less failprone, but will fail here: https://jsfiddle.net/7d9qkcbw/1/

Comment: @connexo OP only asked about how their code is right now. Didn't mention anything to do with extra classes within their elements so it seems somewhat irrelevant

Comment: Fine, but good to mention for other guys reading this post in the future.

Comment: @connexo Why have you edited my answer? It's a pointless addition for the reasons I've explained above.

Comment: It's a good idea to clearly show weaknesses of an approach that way. Even moreso, since you haven't elaborated on the prerequisites your approach expects.

Comment: @skobaljic that's not a bug at all. It's just reading the entire `className` property value and comparing the starting value. Using an attribute selector on classes (while it may work in this case) is always a very big code smell which should be investigated and avoided where possible.

Comment: @connexo But we go off what OP provided. You're assuming that there **will** be extra classes in their div elements and then you're coming up with a solution for it. OP hasn't specified that there **will** be. Until that is done, you shouldn't assume and alter the original question asked and provide a potential solution for what seems like extra kudos. Especially on someone else's answer. We could do that for a multitude of things and come up with fixes for 'weak approaches' - not just extra classes being potentially used.